# why isn't this html5 canvas animation working?

Tags: html, animation, canvas, setinterval

So I'm trying to develop an understanding of animation in Canvas, but for some reason this code isn't working. The yellow rectangle shows up but the position does not iterate. This script is referenced as `<script src = "images/drawing.js"></script>` in my html code. Here is drawing.js:

```
 var x = 400;
 var y = 300;

 function init() {

     var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
     var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
     canvas.width = 800;
     canvas.height = 600;

     context.fillStyle = "black";
     context.fillRect(x,y,150,150);
     setInterval(animateBox(context), 30);

 }



 function animateBox(context) {

     context.clearRect(0,0,context.canvas.width,context.canvas.height);
     x += 5;
     context.fillStyle = "yellow";
     context.fillRect(x,y,150,150);
 }
```

Comment: "Isn't work" is not a very good description...

Comment: You're right I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `setInterval(animateBox(context), 30);` to

```
setInterval(function(){
    animateBox(context)
}, 30);
```

I think that is the problem. The question is kinda vague. Ensure you are calling the `init()` function too (though you probably are).